# text overlay on hover with mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'd like to add an animated text overlay on an `a>img` with some simple effect like fade or animate in/out.

Does anyone know of a plugin that already does this, or can suggest the mootools functions I should be looking at?

Comment: something similar to this
http://jcargoo.110mb.com/textimages/image.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to translate the following pseudocode into Mootools: -

1. Write a function which creates a new `<div>` element inside a given element, using the `new Element()` function.  The content of the `<div>` will be passed through in the function arguments in addition to the parent element.
2. Add a `mouseenter` event to the `<a>` tag you want to work on which triggers the above function and passes itself as the parent element.  You could set the rel attribute of the parent `<a>` tag to be the content of the child `<div>` to make this plugin really dynamic.
3. Create a `slideOut()` function which takes an element, finds the dimensions of the parent element and carries out a slide animation to move the element outside the parent elements bounds.  Make sure you have `overflow:hidden;` set on the parent elements CSS.
4. Add a mouseout event to the `<a>` tag which runs the `slideOut()` function and passes the child `<div>` as it's argument.

That should do it.